# how can i iterate default attribute in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

```
class Ticket:
    availableSeats = 10

    def __init__(self, availableSeats, eventName, ticketId, date, time, venue):
        self.availableSeats = availableSeats
        self.eventName = eventName
        self.ticketId = ticketId
        self.date = date
        self.time = time

    def updateSeatsAvailable(self):
        self.availableSeats = self.availableSeats-1
        return self.availableSeats
```

so what i want is when first instance of ticket is create then the attribute availableseats change to 9 and when another instance is created the availableseats change to 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `availableSeats` is a property of *events*, you should have a registry of events mapping event names / event ids to a number of available seats.

I guess this coult be stored on the class, though the intialisation of the tickets makes very little sense:

```py
class Ticket:
    events = {}

    def __init__(self, availableSeats, eventName, ticketId, date, time, venue):
        self.events.setdefault(eventName, availableSeats)
        self.eventName = eventName
        self.ticketId = ticketId
        self.date = date
        self.time = time

    def updateSeatsAvailable(self):
        self.events[self.eventName] -= 1
        return self.events[self.eventName]
```

Though as far as I'm concerned, `Ticket` instances should probably have a link back to an event object, said event object would be storing event-related information (available seats, possibly date, time and venue depending).

Conversedly, `Ticket` should be renamed to `Event`, the ticketId should not be part of it, possibly other fields shouldn't either depending on the handling of e.g. multi-day or multi-venue events (but then the event should probably store validation informations relating to these).

Also don't see the point of `availableSeats` on the class, it's completely unused.

And I see no relation whatsoever between the title of the question and the body.